# How can I simplify my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a newbie developer, I created a layout which matches my expectations but I fear that its  construction is too complex.

I used many layouts but I don't see how to build a similar layout without mixing linear and relative layouts, is it possible?

How can I simplify this layout?
Thank you for your ideas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/black_blue_gradient"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="24dip" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01left"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/b_bgradient" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/oranwall_ovosh" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout02right"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#E9EEF2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/My_txt"
            android:textColor="#535A5F"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using multiple layouts to achieve your desired results.  In the final compiled apps, XML are stored in binary form and the loading is very fast.  You do have a couple of empty LinearLayouts (header and footer) - what is their purpose?  Can you delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it. Don't forget put your background and other resources

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/perm" />

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/footer"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
                </TableRow>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not? I found it handy to control your layout appearance in many cases

Comment: Great idea, but my footer can only be under the left part

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes I would make:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- I don't understand the point of this one: -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/black_blue_gradient"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="24dip" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout01left"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <!-- I don't understand the point of this one -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/footer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/b_bgradient" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/oranwall_ovosh" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout02right"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#E9EEF2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/My_txt"
                android:textColor="#535A5F"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: For now, they're contains only degraded (I use a color code to help the user to locate in the app) I agree, they can easily be replaced by a TextView with a background